# Websocket keeps disconnecting with new ant media SDK

Tags: ant-media-server-sdk

We upgraded the SDK from 2.2.1 to 2.3.2, but did not change anything in our js application (we did not find updates of the documentation).

We had no issues with the previous SDK and we are still using it in production.

When i connect to the application, I get connected and instantly disconnected from the websocket.

We end up with a websocket closing with this reason `The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages`

Are there any updates we have to do (front or server side)?
Furthermore, screen share does not seem to work anymore.